# Как сделать блок строго по центру?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, выравнивание

Как сделать блок по центру? он смещен немного вправо. Так не должно быть. Верстаю с bootstrap. Помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#second {
 background: #f7f7f7;
 height: 653px;
 width: 1040px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
.second_content_center {
 margin-top: -88px;
 padding: 1px;
 background: #fff;
 height: 650px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 9;
}
.form_contacts_left h4 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.form_contacts_left span {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
.form_contacts_left_email_icon {
 margin-right: 26px;
 margin-bottom: 47px;
}
.form_contacts_left_phones_icon {
 margin-right: 33px;
 margin-bottom: 47px;
}
.form_contacts_left_skype_icon {
 margin-right: 26px;
}
.form_contacts {
 background: #11b2f5;
 width: 100%;
 height: 468px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin-top: 53px;
 padding: 1px;
}
.form_heading_contacts {
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.form_text_contacts {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form_input_contacts {
 width: 90%;
 height: 53px;
 background: #30c2ff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 35px;
}
.form_btn_contacts {
 width: 90%;
 height: 55px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 9px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.form_contacts_left {
 margin-top: 130px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.form_input_contacts::placeholder {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: 300px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #b5e5ff;
}
.form_input_contacts:hover::placeholder {
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="second">
  <div class="second_content_center">
   <h3 class="form_contacts_heading text-center">Мы всегда на связи и ответим на все интересующие Вас вопросы!</h3>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-sm-5">   
      <div class="form_contacts_left">
       <div class="form_contacts_left_phones d-flex">
        <div class="form_contacts_left_phones_icon">
         <img src="img/phones.png" alt="phones">
        </div>
        <div class="form_contacts_left_phones_text">
         <h4>Телефоны</h4>
         <span>В Болгарии  8 (123) 12-123-123</span><br>
         <span>В России     8 (495) 12-123-123</span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form_contacts_left_email d-flex">
        <div class="form_contacts_left_email_icon">
         <img src="img/email.png" alt="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form_contacts_left_email_text">
         <h4>E-MAIL</h4>
         <span>info@sitename.ru</span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form_contacts_left_skype d-flex">
        <div class="form_contacts_left_skype_icon">
         <img src="img/skype.png" alt="skype">
        </div>
        <div class="form_contacts_left_skype_text">
         <h4>Skype</h4>
         <span>skypename</span>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 ml-auto text-center">
      <div class="form_contacts">
       <h2 class="form_heading_contacts"><span>Есть вопросы</span><br>
        по переезду в болгарию?</h2>
        <p class="form_text_contacts">Мы проконсультируем<br>
        Вас бесплатно!</p>
       <form action="#">
        <input class="form_input_contacts" type="text" placeholder="Имя"><br>
        <input class="form_input_contacts" type="email" placeholder="E_MAIL"><br>
        <input class="form_input_contacts" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон"><br>
        <button class="form_btn_contacts">Заказать консультацию</button>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так:

```css
.row{margin:auto;}
#second {
 background: #f7f7f7;
 height: 653px;
 width: 1040px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
.second_content_center {
 margin-top: -88px;
 padding: 1px;
 background: #fff;
 height: 650px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 9;
}
.form_contacts_left h4 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.form_contacts_left span {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
.form_contacts_left_email_icon {
 margin-right: 26px;
 margin-bottom: 47px;
}
.form_contacts_left_phones_icon {
 margin-right: 33px;
 margin-bottom: 47px;
}
.form_contacts_left_skype_icon {
 margin-right: 26px;
}
.form_contacts {
 background: #11b2f5;
 width: 100%;
 height: 468px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin-top: 53px;
 padding: 1px;
}
.form_heading_contacts {
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.form_text_contacts {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form_input_contacts {
 width: 90%;
 height: 53px;
 background: #30c2ff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 35px;
}
.form_btn_contacts {
 width: 90%;
 height: 55px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 9px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.form_contacts_left {
 margin-top: 130px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.form_input_contacts::placeholder {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: 300px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #b5e5ff;
}
.form_input_contacts:hover::placeholder {
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="second">
  <div class="second_content_center">
   <h3 class="form_contacts_heading text-center">Мы всегда на связи и ответим на все интересующие Вас вопросы!</h3>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-sm-5">   
      <div class="form_contacts_left">
       <div class="form_contacts_left_phones d-flex">
        <div class="form_contacts_left_phones_icon">
         <img src="img/phones.png" alt="phones">
        </div>
        <div class="form_contacts_left_phones_text">
         <h4>Телефоны</h4>
         <span>В Болгарии  8 (123) 12-123-123</span><br>
         <span>В России     8 (495) 12-123-123</span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form_contacts_left_email d-flex">
        <div class="form_contacts_left_email_icon">
         <img src="img/email.png" alt="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form_contacts_left_email_text">
         <h4>E-MAIL</h4>
         <span>info@sitename.ru</span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form_contacts_left_skype d-flex">
        <div class="form_contacts_left_skype_icon">
         <img src="img/skype.png" alt="skype">
        </div>
        <div class="form_contacts_left_skype_text">
         <h4>Skype</h4>
         <span>skypename</span>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 ml-auto text-center">
      <div class="form_contacts">
       <h2 class="form_heading_contacts"><span>Есть вопросы</span><br>
        по переезду в болгарию?</h2>
        <p class="form_text_contacts">Мы проконсультируем<br>
        Вас бесплатно!</p>
       <form action="#">
        <input class="form_input_contacts" type="text" placeholder="Имя"><br>
        <input class="form_input_contacts" type="email" placeholder="E_MAIL"><br>
        <input class="form_input_contacts" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон"><br>
        <button class="form_btn_contacts">Заказать консультацию</button>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Не получилось.. У меня же блок этот перекрывает секцию.. И у него отрицательный марджин топ..

Comment: @Roman попробуйте `margin-left:auto;` и `margin-right:auto;`. Должно помочь..